# Android create directory hierarchy

Tags: java, android, file, directory

I created a directory programmatically and i inserted photos :

```
File dirGallery = context.getDir("Gallery", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(dirGallery, photo);
...
```

This is working !

But now i want to create a directory in my existing directory "Gallery" and insert other photos.
I tried :

```
File dirGallery = context.getDir("Gallery/Gallery2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

But i get "File ... contains a path separator".

I also tried :

```
File dirGallery = context.getDir("Gallery", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
dirGallery.mkdir();
File dirGallery2 = new File(dirGallery,"Gallery2");
dirGallery2.mkdir();
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(dirGallery2, nomPhoto);
```

And when i get my file :

```
File dirGallery = context.getDir("Gallery", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File dirGallery2 = new File(dirGallery,"Gallery2");
File[] listImages = dirGallery2.listFiles(filter);
```

But listImages is empty. Where did i fail ?

TY

Comment: What does dirGallery2.listFiles() return? i.e. without passing any filter.

Comment: It doesn't change anything, with ou without, my working code is still working and my fail code still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing this:

```
File dirRecipe = context.getDir("Gallery/Gallery2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

try this:

```
File dirRecipe = context.getDir("Gallery"+File.separator+"Gallery2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

this should create the folder inside of folder as you want.

Comment: This is not working, i still have the error : "File ... contains a path separator".

Comment: Ok my bad, i tested during hours but i forgot to delete my application, the corrupted file was still there and crashed my application. TY Emil ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can not pass a directory structure (e.g. a/b/c) to GetDir(), the following will work however:

```
    File dir = getFilesDir();
    File dir2 = new File(dir, "test1/test2");
    dir2.mkdirs();
```

this will create the directory structure

/data/data/com.somename.someclass/files/test1/test2